# How to edit curve, but not ruined tilt settings?

Tags: bezier-curves

[image: Roller Coaster - tilt is set up correctly]
Here I have Roller Coaster set up correctly, but let's move only one random handle and let's look how the whole roller coaster set up is getting ruined.

[image: Moving one random handle ruins whole set up, I have to repair this by hand?]
Everything is ruined, do I really need to set again every tilt for every handle again? And If I again will need to change something, Will I have to change tilt everywhere again?

Help please ; (

Comment: What is the curve twisting mode set to?

Comment: Minimum. Is there a lot of difference  between those options?

Comment: I'm not a big fan of curve modeling, but in general whenever I see this weird things happening, I always make sure to apply scale for both curve and path, and always use Ctrl + T to control tilt in Control Points, do not use Rotate.

Comment: Check that [proportional editing](https://www.blender.org/manual/editors/3dview/transform/transform_control/proportional_edit.html) is disabled.

Comment: This behavior is crazy and should be treated as a bug in my opinion...

Answer (score 5):

I think you might want to change tilting to *Z-Up* under the Properties Window > Object Data Tab > Shape Panel

Although it is not perfect it will probably be the closest to a correct "always up" tilt. You can then manually adjust whichever parts are not supposed to point up, which I believe are probably a minority compared to the tilting curves.

From my admittedly limited testing with *Z-Up* changing other parts of the curve has no effect on the already established tilts

Comment: I tried to do so, but the problem was when the Roller Coaster was drivin' straight down and doing spiral at the same time (You can not see it from the Top View). So I think that for now, I need to do adjust tilts by hand every time I change position of any handle, which is really a big pain in the A.