# Curve Spiral creates unwanted result with mesh

Tags: modifiers, bezier-curves

I have been trying to recreate Min-mins left arm from ARMS but to no avail... I created a spiral myself and tried to wrap the mesh along it using the array and curve modifiers. The mesh does not stay consistent along the spiral however, turning inside out and back in throughout a cycle of the spiral creating an inconsistent shape. I tried it with the spiral given from the extra curve add-on which unfortunately yielded the same results. I don't really know how to fix this. Attached should be a reference photo of what it should look like. Note that the scales and spikes are always on the outside. This is what I want to accomplish.

[image: myProblem]

[image: reference]

Comment: Try the built in Extra Objects addon.  It has an option for creating spirals.

Comment: that's what I meant by  _I tried it with the spiral given from the extra curve add-on which unfortunately yielded the same results_

Comment: Try to set "Object > Transform > Geometry to Origin",
it looks like your geometry is offset from center.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Object on curve wont stay flat!](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/71787/object-on-curve-wont-stay-flat)

Comment: Also see https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/49265/how-to-edit-curve-but-not-ruined-tilt-settings/49289#49289

Comment: @jim both of the origins are at the center and overlapping. I know that I can alter some of the position/rotation of the mesh on the curve within edit mode but that doesn't fix the complete 180 in and back during the spiral. The mesh in edit mode is a little bit away from the center but that was necessary so the array modifier would work cohesively with the curve modifier. The origin is still at 0,0,0 as is the origin of the curve.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem could be solved simply by tilting the curve a bit. The to me previously unknown shortcut ctrl+t allowed me to tilt the curve in such a way that it worked out in the end. For those that don't know: tilting a curve doesn't move any of the points on a curve but changes the direction they are facing.