# Can someone explain how I can make this corner flat and flow into an incline?

Tags: modeling, bezier-curves

I'm trying to build a track for Assetto Corsa for the first time and I'm having trouble making the corner flat and curve into an incline.

[image]

Comment: Related https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/49265/how-to-edit-curve-but-not-ruined-tilt-settings

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Object on curve wont stay flat!](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/71787/object-on-curve-wont-stay-flat)

Answer (score 1):

To fix that you need to tilt original curve. Open the curve in edit mode, select points, that you want to tilt, and press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>T</kbd>. Then rotate it like in a rotation tool.

Comment: What I did was, was attach a plane to a path curve. What you suggested did not work. It stayed the same as in the picture.