# How to remove unwanted tilt from bezier curve path

Tags: modifiers, bezier-curves

I'm trying to use an array and a curve modifier to create a simple track along a single bezier curve.

[image]

I've run into a small issue though when I try to have the path curve around a corner while also lowering elevation at the same time:

[image]
[image]
[image]

After the sloped turn completes and straightens out, the path becomes tilted despite all control handles having `0` tilt:

[image]

After this point, the tilting remains along the path unless I manually tilt in the opposite direction to offset but I don't like this since it seems incorrect and I don't know an exact number to use as a tilt offset.

Tilting doesn't occur if the turn is made while keeping the control handles at the same z-axis height:

[image]

**How can I ensure the path is always facing straight up along the z-axis (unless I add tilt)?**

Comment: Have you tried, in the curve's data panel, switching the 'Twisting' property to 'Z-Up'?

Comment: https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/49265/how-to-edit-curve-but-not-ruined-tilt-settings

Comment: Thanks Robin and Duarte, editing the Twist Method was exactly what I needed. TIL!