# How can I avoid this unwanted rotation in an object with curve modifier?

Tags: modifiers, bezier-curves

I'm trying to make a handrail but i get this unwanted rotation. I want the start and the end of the handrail to have the same rotation (flat).

I used a long subdivided cube to show it better, you can see that at the start it is flat like I want it but at the end it gets rotated by something like 40 degrees.

If I use a curve with the bevel option instead of an object with the curve modifier i get the same problem.

[image]

[image]

Comment: Did you try changing the tilt of your curve control points?

Comment: https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/49265/how-to-edit-curve-but-not-ruined-tilt-settings/49289

Comment: Thank you so much!! it worked perfectly :)