# Object Bevel on Curve twists around curve when moving any curve point

Tags: bezier-curves, hair

I'm working on using curves to make hair. The curves have a profile bevel which is a shape I've created from another curve. When I move the points around, however, the orientation of that bevel profile rotates around the curve to the inside.

For example, I'm working on a character that has curly hair. The front has a big curly part (like Luca's). When I edit the points to make it curl around, almost in a tunnel, the part of the hair on the outside rotates around to the inside.

I can twist it all back by selecting all the points and using ctrl t to twist them all back, but then there are weird dents or folds in the hair, as seen in the last image. If I could just manipulate the points without the design rotating around the curve, I'd be good.

[image: before moving the hair points]

[image: after i twist all the points to 'fix' the problem]

Here's what happens when I move the points where they're supposed to be.

[image: what happens when i move the points where they're supposed to be]

Comment: Hello and welcome. Please use a title that reflects the content of the question. It should be succinct, unique and identifying, and summarize what the issue is so that users can at a glance broadly understand what your post is about before opening it. Use the [edit] link below your post and avoid any emojis salutations or extraneous text not essential to the question. Remember, your title is the first thing potential visitors will see, and will weight heavily on their decision to open your question, which will directly affect the number of answers you might get.

Comment: https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/49265/how-to-edit-curve-but-not-ruined-tilt-settings

Comment: 2 things: experiment with different tilt interpolation in properties/object data/active spline to reduce "dents"; to reduce tilt, make your curve pointing in +x and rotate in object mode to +z instead, and don't adjust the tilt on the first (root) control in the curve.

Comment: Hi Nathan, Thank you for the suggestions, unfortunately I didn't experience much success with the active spline settings. Additionally, I'm unsure exactly what you mean with the x and z axes, can you explain that part again please? Thank you.